# How to stop Kafka logging to nohup.out file

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, nohup

In the shell script runMyProgram.sh, the app is starting with this command:

nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher >> nohup.out 2>&1 &

As soon as it starts, the nohup.out file is getting filled with Kafka certificate information, algorithm names, for example: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 254,
followed by encoded/decoded text.

I've tried changing the ">> nohup.out 2>&1" to other forms and combinations, didn't help.

I've also tried setting all those package/classes level logging to OFF/FATAL/ERROR/in log4j2.xml file, that too didn't solve the problem.

Like so:

```
<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
  <level value="OFF" />
  <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_ROOT"/></logger>
```

I've also excluded log4j from pom dependencies, didn't resolve either, like so:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</exclusion></exclusions></dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting to dev/null

```
 nohup command_to_run  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

More info here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device

Comment: Nothing will be logged then.
I don't want Kafka information to be logged there. 
If there are errors, then I want to see those (Why the app didn't start or which configurations are not correct)

Comment: I've understood that you don't want any logs in nohup.out file. If you want to log only error please try something like this:

nohup your_command < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> error.log

Works for me.

Comment: I just tried that, added a context initialization error to check error logging. It didn't show it. 
I have a log running in ./logs dir, which showed me the error, but no error in nohup.out.